# PhoneGap iPhone unable to send email

Tags: email, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I tried adding the [EmailComposer](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/EmailComposer) plugin to my iPhone app but always gives me error:

`Failed to load webpage with error: The requested URL was not found on this server.`

I ever tried modifying the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` as:

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];

    if ( [ [url scheme] isEqualToString:@"mailto"] ) 
    { 
        return YES; 
    } else { 
    return [self.viewController webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
    } 
}
```

but still it gives me the same error. Has anyone integrated Email feature in any iPhone app using PhoneGap.

I'm using PhoneGap 1.4.1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if are using phonegap, you can use this JavaScript code

```
window.location = 'mailto:test@example.com?body=Hello World Message';
```

or direct html link

```
<a href="mailto:test@example.com?body=Hello World Message">send to friend</a>
```

I hope that's help you.